# jdbc connecting to ms access database

Tags: java, jdbc

In this code segment I want to get the output of values I stored in ms access. however, every step I found in this program is good. but it's output is inconsequential. no any exception or errors occurs. just showing the output is `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`. my code is given below:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class TestDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName = ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:kundan");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from kumar";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("\n" + rs.getString(1) + "\t" + rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3) + "\t" + rs.getString(4));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is inconsequential here?

Comment: Which java version do you use? change `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` to `ex.printStacktrace()` to see the full exception.

Comment: He said there was no exception. But I cannot see how the code above would ever render a printout of the driver name (btw that string is never used anyway).

Comment: I use jdk 1.7...I changed the String Driver to Class.forName...then it's showing the output of sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver....Actually I am student...i'm keen to do programming...b8 some unidentified(no meaningful) errors comes out which makes me fed up

Comment: According to the message, it might be that the driver was not found. Follow @Jens advice and change the line that handles exception.

Comment: have you properly set the ODBC resource in the OS environment?

Comment: finally..it's showing the Exception type of  classNotFoundException:sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.....yes I set the Odbc in os environment